# Escaping GET parameters

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have `<form>` on my page containing a `<textarea>`, and I want to send the text entered in it using Ajax. The text goes to a PHP page, where I insert it into a SQL database.

The problem I am facing is that whenever I write `+` or `&` in the `<textarea>`, JavaScript treats them as special characters in the URL. How can I escape them?

```
function getMessageResponse() {
    var xmlHttp;

    try {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        // Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            document.myform.post.value = '';
            retrieve();
        }
    }

    var url = "wall4.php";
    url = url+"?post=" + document.myform.post.value; 

    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Too many ellipses, not enough question marks.

Comment: It really sounds like you want to use a POST request, not a GET request.

Comment: Dear God!!! Have you never herd of jQuery. It takes care of all of that you. "Write less, do more"

Comment: Actually,I tried Jquery But I found it difficult....

Comment: Strongly advise you watch https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) your parameter:

```
url = url + "?post=" + encodeURIComponent(document.myform.post.value);
```